# API Gateway pattern using RPC service fabrics

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

We have 3 service

1. eShopCustomer
2. eShopCart
3. eShopPayments
4. eShopOrders

So in order to communicate between these microservices we create an another webapi project called eShopAPI as gatway for communicating with the above microservices using RPC model from the eShopAPI. So eShopAPI project is the REST API exposed.

Is the process is good?

Let see some example code below how we are exposing

```
   [ServiceRequestActionFilter]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OrderController : ApiController
{
    IOrderService _orderService = ServiceProxy.Create<IOrderService>(new Uri("fabric:/eShop/OrderService"));
    ICartService _cartService = ServiceProxy.Create<ICartService>(new Uri("fabric:/eShop/CartService"));

    // GET api/values/5 
    [Route("api/order/{id}")]
    public string CreateOrder([FromBody] OrderViewmodel model)
    {
        _orderService.CreateOrder(id);
        _cartService.AddItems();
        return "value";
    }

}


[ServiceRequestActionFilter]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BasketController : ApiController
{
    IBasketService _orderService = ServiceProxy.Create<IBasketService>(new Uri("fabric:/eShop/BasketService"));


    // GET api/values/5 
    [Route("api/order/{id}")]
    public string Get(long id)
    {
        _orderService.GetOrder(id);
        return "value";
    }

}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Why not use something like kong ( https://getkong.org/ )?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest u not to keep your business logic in the api layer but to use N-Tier  architecture. In my opinion u need another orchestration layer (stateless service/services) which will be responsible for the flow of a service request(validation,orchestration etc)